# How to write the below piece of code using macro function?

Tags: c++, macros, inline

**How should I write the below piece of code using macro function?**

```
#ifdef LOG_ENABLED      
    m_logger->Log(szType,szMessage);
#endif
```

***I have done something like mentioned below and it resulted in error:-***

```
#define _LOG_MSG_CND_BEGIN_ #ifdef LOG_ENABLED
#define _LOG_MSG_CND_END_ #endif
#define WriteLogMessage(szType,szMessage) \
{\
_LOG_MSG_CND_BEGIN_\
    m_logger->Log(szType,szMessage);\
_LOG_MSG_CND_END_\
}
```

Please let me know how to write macro function for the above three piece of code without any errors.

I have used inline function for the same piece of code but while debugging i saw that the inline function was not getting treated as inline function and so i want to use macro function in this case.

**Inline function which i used was as mentioned below:-**

```
inline void WriteLogMessage(LOG_LEVEL szType, LPCTSTR szMessage){
#ifdef LOG_ENABLED      
    m_logger->Log(szType,szMessage);
#endif
}
```

Comment: I don't know how you've concluded that your inline function wasn't treated as one, but I'm sure in the release build, with optimizations on, it will be inlined.

Comment: @enobayram: i was debugging and checked whenever the inline function is called it was behaving as a normal function. By the way i was checking windows mobile 6.5 device. Is there any dependency w.r.t platforms?

Comment: May I know why the question has been down voted? I am asking the genuine doubt which i am getting.

Comment: @Abhineet: Presumably, you were debugging a debug build, with optimisations disabled; functions are generally only inlined when that optimisation is enabled.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Thanks a lot for your advice. I will check with that as  i have not checked with that option.

Comment: @Abhineet:  I did not downvote, but I can guess.  Two reasons.  First you're using macros to begin with.  Macros suck, your best bet is to not use them unless you have to.  Second, the premise of your question -- that you do have to because `inline` doesn't work -- would appear to be incorrect.  You have all optimizations turned off when you run under Debug.  Possibly three, why do you care if `inline` isn't having an effect?

Comment: @Abhineet I don't think the question should have been downvoted; downvotes should be about the form, and not the content. However, I completely agree with John. Back to the issue of inlining, modern compilers are optimizing (when told to) waaay more than you think. They will probably do any **refactoring** that you would also do yourself to speed up the execution.

Comment: @John Dibling: Since i was unaware of "optimizations turned off" when i was running under debug mode and due to which i was wondering that why inline function is not invoked at the place where it is called and because of which i thought to use macros. So this was my obvious doubt to perform the above code through macros. Your question - Why do you care if inline... ? Because i was looking for efficiency.

Comment: Re efficiency:  Let the compiler do it's job.  It is far better at optimizing your code than you could ever hope to be.

Comment: @John Dibling: I am using that three piece of code at 30 location,,, since i was wondering abt inline i thought if inline is not treated as inline then the efficiency will drop  down as it will be called 30 times from different place and so i thought to use macros. Anyhow i understood ur point too..

Comment: @Abhineet:  Did you profile your code (in *release*!) and prove that the 30 function calls were an actual bottleneck in your code?  If not, you optimized prematurely.  I'd be willing to be $0.42 that this is not a problem that you need to solve.

Comment: @JohnDibling: To be frank with u, the answer to your question is,, NO, it was not a bottleneck.. Only thing which came into my mind after debugging was that inline function is not treating as inline and so i need to look for some other alternatives and at moment time i thought abt macro function since i was unaware with the magic of compiler which i came to know only after Mike Seymour comments.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I am still sad the question was downvoted....

Comment: @Abhineet:  I hear you.  Look at it this way.  You paid a few reputation points, but you learned a few new things, didn't you?  Would you say you're better off for the experience?

Comment: @JohnDibling: Yes u r right.. Thanks a lot for your advice.. I am happy that i learnt sth new... Atleast my dbt is clarified...

Comment: @Abhineet:  You're welcome.  Oh and by the way, you owe me $0.42. :)  (Just kidding)

Comment: @JohnDibling: Ofcourse anytime,,, come and visit INDIA and i will definitely pay :) and will grab your knowledge as much as I can..

Answer (score 3):

The standard C preprocessor is a bit of an idiot and doesn't understand much at all. You want something like this:

```
#if defined LOG_ENABLED
#define WriteLogMessage(szType,szMessage) m_logger->Log(szType,szMessage)
#else
#define WriteLogMessage(szType,szMessage)
#endif
```

Comment: No i dont want this. That i have already performed. What i want is clearly mentioned above. I want that three line of code as a macro function.


#ifdef LOG_ENABLED      
    m_logger->Log(szType,szMessage);
#endif

Comment: @Nick: I am not rude at all dear. I am telling what i am expecting. Anyway if you feel this I am sorry for that. And thanks a lot Skizz for your valuable answer.

Comment: @Abhineet: Not sure what you mean by "macro function". However, the above is a fairly standard way of doing conditionally compiled code. So, having the code `WriteLogMessage (AType, "AMessage");` will generate either `m_logger->Log (AType, "AMessage");` when `LOG_ENABLED` is defined and no code at all when `LOG_ENABLED` is not defined.

Comment: @Skizz: No Skizz I asked how to put that three piece of code using macros function. I know how to use the condition. I only don't know was how to replace that three line of code using macros. I hope you got it what i mean to say.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor directives need to be the first thing in a line:

```
#define _LOG_MSG_CND_BEGIN_ 
#ifdef LOG_ENABLED
#define _LOG_MSG_CND_END_ 
#endif
#define WriteLogMessage(szType,szMessage) \
{\
_LOG_MSG_CND_BEGIN_\
    m_logger->Log(szType,szMessage);\
_LOG_MSG_CND_END_\
}
```

EDIT: If you want macros to be expanded to other macros, that's not possible.

Comment: I think what he wants to do is have `_LOG_MSG_CND_BEGIN_` be expanded as `#ifdef LOG_ENABLED`.

Comment: @interjay that's not possible.

Comment: I know it's not possible, but putting it in separate lines will serve no purpose.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: I have one dbt. I need to write the log message only if LOG_ENABLED is set active. So how it will perform the check using #define _LOG_MSG_CND_BEGIN_ ?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: So do you mean to say that i should go with inline function or appending the three line of code wherever needed?

Comment: @Abhineet If Skizz's answer does what you need, do that. But i'd go with inline functions, just like you had in your question.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: No I dont want what Skizz has done.. I just want that three line of code in the form of macro function.